# получить список уже не требующихся плагинов

Tags: jenkins

установил плагин (например, [blue ocean](https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean)), по зависимостям доустановилось несколько плагинов (список, конечно, видел, но зафиксировать забыл).

потом плагин удалил, а те, что автоматически доустановились, так и остались.

как получить список этих автоматически установленных плагинов, чтобы их удалить? хотя бы по критерию «были установлны в такой-то день».

Comment: На английском SO порекомендовали плагин: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Usage+Plugin+(Community)

Comment: Ссылка на вопрос на английском СО: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542644/how-to-list-all-unused-jenkins-plugins

Comment: @Klimenkomud, это абсолютно не то. хотя и кореллирует с заголовком вопроса. // да и данная цитата из описания, кстати, делает его чуть менее чем полностью бесполезным: *Plugins used in pipeline scripts would not be listed normally as used by jobs, because they are used dynamically in Jenkinsfiles*